# Return HTTP status code from Flask without "returning"

Tags: python, flask, gitlab

### Context

- I have a server called `"server.py"` that functions as a post-commit webhook from GitLab.
- Within `"server.py"`, there is a long-running process (~40 seconds)

### SSCCE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
from flask import Flask, abort, jsonify

debug = True

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def compile_metadata():
    # the long running process...
    time.sleep(40)
    # end the long running process
    return jsonify({"success": True})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082, debug=debug, threaded=True)
```

### Problem Statement

GitLab's webhooks expect return codes to be returned quickly.  Since my webhook returns after or around 40 seconds; GitLab sends a retry sending my long running process in a loop until GitLab tries too many times.

### Question

Am I able to return a status code from Flask back to GitLab, but still run my long running process?

I've tried adding something like:

```
...
def compile_metadata():
    abort(200)
    # the long running process
    time.sleep(40)
```

but `abort()` only supports failure codes.

I've also tried using `@after_this_request`:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    @after_this_request
    def compile_metadata(response):
        # the long running process...
        print("Starting long running process...")
        time.sleep(40)
        print("Process ended!")
        # end the long running process
    return jsonify({"success": True})
```

Normally, flask returns a status code only from python's `return` statement, but I obviously cannot use that before the long running process as it will escape from the function.

*Note: I am not actually using `time.sleep(40)` in my code.  That is there only for posterity, and for the SSCCE.  It will return the same result*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`.  After using `threading.Thread`, it proved unhelpful as Flask would still wait for the thread to finish *(even with `t.daemon = True`)*

I achieved the result of returning a status code before the long-running task like such:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

debug = True

app = Flask(__name__)
pool = Pool(10)


def compile_metadata(data):
    print("Starting long running process...")
    print(data['user']['email'])
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Process ended!")


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    data = request.json
    pool.apply_async(compile_metadata, [data])
    return jsonify({"success": True}), 202


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082, debug=debug, threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have `compile_metadata` spawn a thread to handle the long running task, and then return the result code immediately (i.e., without waiting for the thread to complete).  Make sure to include some limitation on the number of simultaneous threads that can be spawned.

For a slightly more robust and scalable solution, consider some sort message queue based solution like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

For the record, a simple solution might look like:

```
import time
import threading
from flask import Flask, abort, jsonify

debug = True

app = Flask(__name__)

def long_running_task():
    print 'start'
    time.sleep(40)
    print 'finished'

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def compile_metadata():
    # the long running process...
    t = threading.Thread(target=long_running_task)
    t.start()
    # end the long running process
    return jsonify({"success": True})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082, debug=debug, threaded=True)
```

Comment: running another thread was my instinct, if a flask solution does not work - then i will do this for sure.  I'll also take a look at celery

Comment: ok - so i took a look at another thread, and no dice interestingly.  Flask still waited for the thread to finish.  I also tried celery, but it needed a middleman, and was more setup that i wished.  I went with `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`. I'll write an answer, and give you and upvote for your ideas :)

Comment: I actually ran the above code, and it clearly returns immediately while the thread is still running.

Comment: weird... i copied your code verbatim and got `Starting long running process...
Process ended!
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2017 12:14:06] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`  instead of  `127.0.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2017 12:40:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 202 -
Starting long running process...
Process ended!`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to return a response from the server quickly, and still do some time consuming work, generally you should use some sort of shared storage like Redis to quickly store all the stuff you need, then return your status code. So the request gets served very quickly.

And have a separate server routinely work that semantic job queue to do the time consuming work. And then remove the job from the queue once the work is done. Perhaps storing the final result in shared storage as well. This is the normal approach, and it scales very well. For example, if your job queue grows too fast for a single server to keep up with, you can add more servers to work that shared queue.

But even if you don't need scalability, it's a very simple design to understand, implement, and debug. If you ever get an unexpected spike in request load, it just means that your separate server will probably be chugging away all night long. And you have peace of mind that if your servers shut down, you won't lose any unfinished work because they're safe in the shared storage.

But if you have one server do everything, performing the long running tasks asynchronously in the background, I guess maybe just make sure that the background work is happening like this:

```
------------ Serving Responses
    ----     Background Work
```

And not like this:

```
----    ---- Serving Responses
    ----     Background Work
```

Otherwise it would be possible that if the server is performing some block of work in the background, it might be unresponsive to a new request, depending on how long that time consuming work takes (even under very little request load). But if the client times out and retries, I think you're still safe from performing double work. But you're not safe from losing unfinished jobs.